# Joomla Site move Sef problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

i am trying to figure this out for a couple of hours.
I am in the process of upgrading my joomla site from 1.5 to 2.5
I did all the work needed in an offline copy, i uploaded my new joomla site in a sub folder of root in "/v2" folder.

With my Joomla SEF links on i can't even use my template (blank page with post texts).
They work if i remove them but then i have other problems with Virtumart Search.

I already changed paths in configuration.php (cache,logs) and edited my .htaccess in my subfolder to have
"RewriteBase /v2".

The odd is that if i enable the default template is working.
I am really furstrated here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the base url in the configuration.php file